# Why is my PDF contents not displaying in my Literal control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

I am saving database files in SQL Server Management Studio. I have a gridview control that displays the PDF files that are stored in my database. I also have a linkbutton "View" that is suppose to view to the corresponding file. The problem I am having is that the contents are not showing in my literal control. EDIT: I'm still having problems getting the contents to display in my literal control. I am getting the error: Invalid attempt to read when no data is present. The error I'm getting is at this line: 
bytes = (byte[])sdr["Attachment"];
I'm not quite sure what else to try but here is my code I have so far:

This is my Handler that is called which uses the ID from the QueryString. It is suppose to fetch the File data. here is the code for my handler:

```
public class FileCS : IHttpHandler
{
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    int id = int.Parse(context.Request.QueryString["id"]);
    byte[] bytes;
    string fileName, contentType;
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PALM3ConnectionString2"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Attachment FROM Support_Doc WHERE SupportDocID=@SupportDocID";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SupportDocID", id);
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                sdr.Read();
                bytes = (byte[])sdr["Attachment"];
                contentType = sdr["Name"].ToString();
                fileName = sdr["Type"].ToString();

            }
            con.Close();
        }
    }
    context.Response.Buffer = true;
    context.Response.Charset = "";
    if (context.Request.QueryString["download"] == "1")
    {
        context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
    }
    context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    context.Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
    context.Response.Flush();
    context.Response.End();
}
public bool IsReusable
{
    get
    {
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

This is my code for handling my linkbutton when it is clicked inside my gridview:

```
 protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //int id = int.Parse((sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument);
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["SupportDocID"]);
        string embed = "<object data=\"{0}{1}\" type=\"application/pdf\" width=\"500%\" height=\"600px\">";
        embed += "If you are unable to view file, you can download from <a href = \"{0}{1}&download=1\">here</a>";
        embed += " or download <a target = \"_blank\" href = \"http://get.adobe.com/reader/\">Adobe PDF Reader</a> to view the file.";
        embed += "</object>";

        ltEmbed.Text = string.Format(embed, ResolveUrl("~/FileCS.ashx?Id="), id);

    }
```

This code uploads the file to my database:

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {  
        string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
        string contentType = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType;
        using (Stream fs = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream)
        {
            using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs))
            {
                byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);
                using (SqlConnection con = Connection.GetConnection())
                {
                    //using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand())
                    //{

                       // com.CommandText = "UploadDoc";
                        //com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    string query = "insert into Support_Doc values (@Type, @Name, @Attachment)";
                    using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query)){
                        com.Connection = con;
                        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", filename);
                        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", contentType);
                        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Attachment", bytes);
                        con.Open();
                        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        Label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                        Label1.Text = "File Uploaded Successfully!";
                        con.Close();
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
  }
```

I have looked everywhere on this with absolutely no luck. Any help I would be soooo grateful!!! Thanks again!!!!!

Comment: What literal control?  Which line throws the error?

Comment: Throws error at this line: int id = int.Parse(context.Request.QueryString["id"]);

Comment: And what is in `context.Request.QueryString["id"]` when this happens?  The error seems to imply that it's `null`.

Comment: I made a mistake, it actually throws an error at int id = int.Parse(context.Request.QueryString["SupportDocID"]); It's holding an ID number. In my Database right now I have 4 PDF documents. 1 to 4.

Comment: How have you confirmed that "it's holding an ID number"?  If the error says that it isn't, then it *probably* isn't.

Comment: Well, in my database... it looks like this:

SupportDocID
1
2
3
4

Numbers are going down from SupportDocID. I can show a picture of whats currently in my database

Comment: `context.Request.QueryString["SupportDocID"]` has nothing to do with your database.  Query string values come from the URL.  What is the URL that you're using to access this handler?  When you debug it, what is the actual value?  Nobody here can debug this on your computer for you.

Comment: Okay sorry, so that's not the error I am getting anymore. I am getting the error: Invalid attempt to read when no data is present. on the line of code: bytes = (byte[])sdr["Attachment"];

Is their anyway I can see if the PDF is actually in my database? It says it's holding Binary data under the Attachment field.

Comment: That error implies that no records were found.  Your code is *assuming* that one was found, but if `sdr.Read()` returns `false` then there was no record.  Hence the error.  Usually this is put in a `while` loop, such as `while (sdr.Read()) { /* perform your operation with the record */ }`  That way when no records are returned by the `SELECT` query (such as in this case) then your code won't try to access the (nonexistent) record.

Comment: Thanks a lot David. I'm curious as to why it says I have binary data in my database. Also, is there another way to throw a PDF file in my database without having to code it?

Comment: Any given record in the database may very well *have* data.  But this query *didn't find any records*.  Which means the `WHERE` clause didn't match anything.  Is this discussion leading to an actual answerable question at some point?  So far you're just jumping from one error to another, changing your mind about what's actually failing.  If you debug this and find what *is* failing and have a question about that, I may be able to help.

Comment: I'm just getting the one error now, I feel like I'm super close, but no luck getting the PDF to display.

Comment: And *what error* would that be?  You should update the question to include your current code and the error you're getting (the error message, which line throws the error, relevant runtime values when it happens, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

This line (and the others like it):

```
bytes = (byte[])sdr["Attachment"];
```

assumes that data is present in the data reader.  However, if this line returns `false`:

```
sdr.Read();
```

then no record was found.  So the error is telling you that you're trying to read a record that isn't there.  It's analogous to trying to read the first element of an empty array (`emptyArray[0]`).

You can use the `bool` return value from `sdr.Read()` to determine whether or not a record exists before trying to read that record.  If you're expecting exactly one record (which the code implies) then something like this should work:

```
if (sdr.Read())
{
    bytes = (byte[])sdr["Attachment"];
    contentType = sdr["Name"].ToString();
    fileName = sdr["Type"].ToString();
}
else
{
    // no record was found, how do you want to proceed?
}
```

What to do in the `else` block is up to you.  Maybe return an error message to the user?  Maybe execute another query to return some "default" PDF to the user?  Something else?  However you want to handle the error condition depends on how you want the system to behave.  The point is that a potential error condition exists and you need to check for it.

Ultimately, a record is being requested which doesn't exist.  So the code needs to be able to account for that.

Comment: I found the problem, the problem was in my Button2_Click event.  I should have used:
    int id = int.Parse((sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument); 
instead of:
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["SupportDocID"]);

I was using it originally but my querystring id that I was using in my handler was set to SupportDocID instead of id. I did add the if else statement for my reader. Thanks David!

Answer (score -1):

```
int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["Id"]);
```

instead of

```
int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["SupportDocID"]);
```